# Got an error "cannot read properties" in my game code

Tags: javascript, properties

I am working on a simple game project on my studies, still not too good at it. I've tried to implement an "if-statement" that limited my game character movements inside the canyon so it could not go through the walls and find itself underground. I thought that it looks pretty good and functional but I still get information in the console that properties x_pos are undefined in line 160. Can someone smarter show me where is my problem? I suppose that I should somehow recall properties inside the if-statement but as far I've tried I just ruined everything and made it messier than this is now.

```js
var gameChar_x;
var gameChar_y;
var floorPos_y;
var scrollPos;
var gameChar_world_x;

var isLeft;
var isRight;
var isFalling;
var isPlummeting;

var trees_x;
var treePos_y;
var collectables;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1024, 576);
  floorPos_y = (height * 3) / 4;
  gameChar_x = width / 2;
  gameChar_y = floorPos_y;
  treePos_y = floorPos_y - 150;

  // Variable to control the background scrolling.
  scrollPos = 0;

  // Variable to store the real position of the gameChar in the game
  // world. Needed for collision detection.
  gameChar_world_x = gameChar_x - scrollPos;

  // Boolean variables to control the movement of the game character.
  isLeft = false;
  isRight = false;
  isFalling = false;
  isPlummeting = false;

  // Initialise arrays of scenery objects.

  canyons = [{
      x_pos: 10,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 270,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 730,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 1010,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 1270,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 1730,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 2010,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 2270,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 2730,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 3010,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 3570,
      width: 80
    },
    {
      x_pos: 3730,
      width: 80
    },
  ];

}

function draw() {
  background(100, 155, 255); // fill the sky blue

  noStroke();
  fill(240, 240, 240);
  rect(0, floorPos_y, width, height / 4); // draw some green ground

  push();
  translate(scrollPos, 0);

  // Draw canyons.
  for (var i = 0; i < canyons.length; i++) {
    drawCanyon(canyons[i]);
    checkCanyon(canyons[i]);
  }


  pop();
  // Draw game character.

  drawGameChar();

  //Logic to make the game character move or the background scroll.


  if (isLeft == true) {
    var spaceLeft = gameChar_x - (canyons[i].x_pos + 20);
    var deltaX = gameChar_y <= floorPos_y ? 4 : Math.min(4, spaceLeft);
    gameChar_x -= deltaX;
  } else {
    scrollPos += 5;
  }
  if (isRight == true) {
    var spaceRight = canyons[i].x_pos + canyons[i].width - 20 - gameChar_x;
    var deltaX = gameChar_y <= floorPos_y ? 4 : Math.min(4, spaceRight);
    gameChar_x += deltaX;
  } else {
    scrollPos -= 5;
  }

  // Logic to make the game character rise and fall.
  //jumping
  if (gameChar_y <= floorPos_y) {
    gameChar_y += 4;
    isFalling = true;
  } else {
    isFalling = false;
  }

  // Update real position of gameChar for collision detection.
  gameChar_world_x = gameChar_x - scrollPos;
}

// ---------------------
// Key control functions
// ---------------------

function keyPressed() {
  console.log(keyCode);
  if (keyCode == 37) {
    isLeft = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == 39) {
    isRight = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == 32 && gameChar_y <= floorPos_y + 5) {
    gameChar_y -= 70;
  }
}

function keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == 37) {
    isLeft = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == 39) {
    isRight = false;
  }
}

// ------------------------------
// Game character render function
// ------------------------------

// Function to draw the game character.

function drawGameChar() {
  // draw game character
  if (isLeft && isFalling) {
    // add your jumping-left code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 6, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 14, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 31, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 46, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 27, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x - 3, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 56, gameChar_x - 3, gameChar_y - 62);
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 63);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x - 6, gameChar_y - 30, gameChar_x - 20, gameChar_y - 35);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 13,
      gameChar_y - 47,
      gameChar_x - 23,
      gameChar_y - 40,
      gameChar_x - 13,
      gameChar_y - 43
    );
  } else if (isRight && isFalling) {
    // add your jumping-right code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 6, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 14, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 31, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 46, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 27, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x + 3, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 56, gameChar_x + 3, gameChar_y - 62);
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 63);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x + 6, gameChar_y - 30, gameChar_x + 20, gameChar_y - 35);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x + 13,
      gameChar_y - 47,
      gameChar_x + 23,
      gameChar_y - 40,
      gameChar_x + 13,
      gameChar_y - 43
    );
  } else if (isLeft) {
    // add your walking left code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 4, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 15);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 6,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x - 17,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x - 6,
      gameChar_y - 36
    );
  } else if (isRight) {
    // add your walking right code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 4, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 15);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x + 6,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x + 17,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x + 6,
      gameChar_y - 36
    );
  } else if (isFalling || isPlummeting) {
    // add your jumping facing forwards code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 23, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 13, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 13, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 36, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 50, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 33, 3, 3);
    //eyes
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 52, 2, 2);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 52, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 61, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 66);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 59, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 66);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 61, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 66);
    //arms
    line(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 37, gameChar_x - 15, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 37, gameChar_x + 15, gameChar_y - 57);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 2,
      gameChar_y - 49,
      gameChar_x - 10,
      gameChar_y - 43,
      gameChar_x + 2,
      gameChar_y - 49
    );
  } else {
    // add your standing front facing code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eyes
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arms
    line(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x - 15, gameChar_y - 17);
    line(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x + 15, gameChar_y - 17);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 2,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x - 10,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x + 2,
      gameChar_y - 39
    );
  }
}

// ---------------------------------
// Canyon render and check functions
// ---------------------------------

// Function to draw canyon objects.

function drawCanyon(t_canyon) {
  fill(99);
  rect(t_canyon.x_pos, floorPos_y, t_canyon.width, height);
  fill(70);
  rect(t_canyon.x_pos + 10, floorPos_y, t_canyon.width - 20, height);
  //water
  fill(123, 193, 239);
  rect(t_canyon.x_pos + 10, floorPos_y + 80, t_canyon.width - 20, height / 4);
}

// Function to check character is over a canyon.

function checkCanyon(t_canyon) {
  if (
    gameChar_world_x > t_canyon.x_pos &&
    gameChar_world_x < t_canyon.x_pos + t_canyon.width &&
    gameChar_y >= floorPos_y
  ) {
    isPlummeting = true;
    gameChar_y += 5;
  } else {
    isPlummeting = false;
  }
}

// ----------------------------------
// Collectable items render and check functions
// ----------------------------------

// Function to draw collectable objects.

function drawCollectable(t_collectable) {
  fill(255, 223, 128);
  noStroke();
  triangle(
    t_collectable.x_pos,
    t_collectable.y_pos,
    t_collectable.x_pos - 8,
    t_collectable.y_pos - 30,
    t_collectable.x_pos + 8,
    t_collectable.y_pos - 30
  );
  fill(165, 23, 105);
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(1);
  ellipse(t_collectable.x_pos, t_collectable.y_pos - 35, 20);
  fill(247, 196, 225);
  ellipse(t_collectable.x_pos, t_collectable.y_pos - 45, 18);
}

// Function to check character has collected an item.

function checkCollectable(t_collectable) {
  if (
    dist(
      gameChar_world_x,
      gameChar_y,
      t_collectable.x_pos,
      t_collectable.y_pos
    ) < 50
  ) {
    t_collectable.isFound = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is too long, please offer an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When you get the error "cannot read property x_pos of undefined", what it means isn't that *x_pos* is undefined but that you have `someObj.x_pos` in your code and *someObj* is undefined.

Comment: Not strictly relevant, but the sooner you learn it the easier your life will be- see where you keep having the same lines of code in different places? Like the fill and stroke settings? Put those into their own function and call that function instead of having the same code in different places. Your code will get shorter, easier to read and if you want to change the stroke weight etc, you will only have to do it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by you trying to use your index `i` outside your for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < canyons.length; i++) {
  drawCanyon(canyons[i]);
  checkCanyon(canyons[i]);
}


pop();
// Draw game character.

drawGameChar();

//Logic to make the game character move or the background scroll.

if (isLeft == true) {
    var spaceLeft = gameChar_x - (canyons[i].x_pos + 20); // Your variable i is not defined here
    var deltaX = gameChar_y <= floorPos_y ? 4 : Math.min(4, spaceLeft);
    gameChar_x -= deltaX;
  } else {
  ...
```

Since `i` is not defined, `canyons[i]` is not defined and so has no property `x_pos`.

EDIT: So to actually give you an answer as to how to fix it, if you move your if statements inside the for loop it should fix your accessing of the `canyons` entries:

```
for (var i = 0; i < canyons.length; i++) {
  drawCanyon(canyons[i]);
  checkCanyon(canyons[i]);

  // Check collisions of player with the canyon
  if (isLeft == true) {
    var spaceLeft = gameChar_x - (canyons[i].x_pos + 20);
    var deltaX = gameChar_y <= floorPos_y ? 4 : Math.min(4, spaceLeft);
    gameChar_x -= deltaX;
  } else {
    scrollPos += 5;
  }
  if (isRight == true) {
    var spaceRight = canyons[i].x_pos + canyons[i].width - 20 - gameChar_x;
    var deltaX = gameChar_y <= floorPos_y ? 4 : Math.min(4, spaceRight);
    gameChar_x += deltaX;
  } else {
    scrollPos -= 5;
  }
}
```

One final node: *Please* comment your code. It makes things so much easier to read through.

Comment: Do You think that I should add one more for loop before this if-statement? Or move if-statement into existing for loop and add another bloke with logic movement that will be applied everywhere but in canyons? F.ex: `if (isLeft) {
  if (gameChar_x > width * 0.2) {
    gameChar_x -= 5;
  } else {
    scrollPos += 5;
  }
}
if (isRight) {
  if (gameChar_x < width * 0.8) {
    gameChar_x += 5;
  } else {
    scrollPos -= 5; // negative for moving against the background
  }
}`

Comment: That's difficult to answer without knowing what you're planning to add in the future. Personally I would put it inside the for loop for now as it groups the handling of each canyon together, but if you're planning on adding more restrictions to movement it might make more sense to have it in it's own separate loop.